# How to filter Firestore documents using Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I follow [this](https://medium.com/flutter-community/building-a-chat-app-with-flutter-and-firebase-from-scratch-9eaa7f41782e) tutorial to create a chat. The code to insert message into Firestore is the follow

```
var _firebaseRef = Firestore.instance.collection("chats");
void sendMessage(String message, String idFrom, ProductModel productModel,
  String fromName) {
String groupChatId;
String idTo = productModel.userId;
if (idFrom.hashCode <= productModel.userId.hashCode) {
  groupChatId = '$idFrom-$idTo';
} else {
  groupChatId = '$idTo-$idFrom';
}

var documentReference = _firebaseRef
    .document(groupChatId)
    .collection(groupChatId)
    .document(DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString());

Firestore.instance.runTransaction((transaction) async {
  await transaction.set(
    documentReference,
    {
      'message': message,
      'idFrom': idFrom,
      "productId": productModel.id,
      "createdAt": utils.currentTime(),
      'timestamp': DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString(),
      "fromName": fromName,
      "idTo": productModel.userId
    },
  );
});
}
```

As you can see the `groupChatId` to be used on `DocumentId` and `CollectionId` is a composition of 2 ids (sender and receiver).

This is what its looks like:
[image]

The code to displey each message works fine

```
 String groupChatId;
if (idFrom.hashCode <= idTo.hashCode) {
  groupChatId = '$idFrom-$idTo';
} else {
  groupChatId = '$idTo-$idFrom';
}

return _firebaseRef
    .document(groupChatId)
    .collection(groupChatId)
    .orderBy('timestamp', descending: true)
    .snapshots();
```

In that picture you can see 1 chat with 1 message, I am trying to display each chat of my current user, to do that I 'd to filter all document inside of `chat` collection, so the user can click it and get list message on chatd detail page.

I don't know how to do that, if you have a better approach to do the chat I will appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `getDocuments` and `then` methods, inside of it you can make your validations, on this case you can if the `documentID`contains your ID. Like this

```
Firestore.instance.collection("chats").getDocuments().then((value) {
      print(value);
      value.documents.forEach((element) {
        if (element.documentID.contains(currentUserId)) {
          DocumentSnapshot document = element;
          print(document);
        }
      });
    });
```

It should works

Answer (score 0):

you can work with something like this querying for where currentUser Id s equal to IdFrom or IdTo

```
StreamBuilder(
               stream: Firestore.instance
                        .collection("users")
                       
                     .orderBy('createAt', descending: true)
                  .where('idFrom', isEqualTo: currentuserId)
                  .where('idTo', isEqualTo: currentuserId)
                        .snapshots(),....
```

if you run this for the first time check your console for a link to create [index](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing)

Comment: I created the chats indexes ``idFrom Ascendente, idTo Ascendente``

Not working using ``Firestore.instance.collection("chats").where("idFrom", isEqualTo: currentUserId).snapshots()``

Comment: when running your app, look for a link in the console ,open the link and it will create the indexes for you..wait for five mins and try again

Comment: You cannot used ``orderBy`` after ``document``. I got ``The method 'orderBy' isn't defined for the type 'DocumentReference'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'orderBy'``

Comment: i have updated my answer..forgot to remove the documnet(); :)Dont forget to mark as answer